# Custom Receiver Not Loading in Chrome Cast Device

Tags: android, chromecast, custom-receiver

I have a chromecast app with a custom receiver served through Google App Engine. My friend added my device and his to the Google Cast SDK Developer console.

As done in CastHelloText example app (https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android), I use the following snippet in my android app:

```
// configure cast device discovery
mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
        .addControlCategory(
                CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.app_id))).build();
mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();
```

**Note:**
I used my app_id that I got from developer console.

For some reasons, my friend is able to load the custom receiver using the Android app. But I am not able to do so. I have done the following with no help:

1) Restart the chrome cast device several times.

2) Factory reset the device.

My current firmware version: 27946

If I use the app_id from CastHelloText app, the same snippet works fine.

How do I confirm that my chrome cast device has loaded/aware of my custom receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have entered the correct serial number (from your device); it is often tricky to read that; take a photo and enlarge that. If problem persists, please contact our [support](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1).

Comment: After some debugging, I found that the problem was due to the serial number. I had wrongly entered "0" instead of "O".